# Plotting vectors of Lat Long coordinates using plotKML function

Tags: r, plot, google-earth

I have a dataframe which has 3000+ observations across 22 variables.

Columns 5:22 contain unique lat long coordinates for each observation, they're not paired i.e. lat long lat long lat long lat long ...... etc. Below is a sample of my dataframe

```
> head(sites,5)
          name    cellName      lat       lon Longitude Latitude        X1       X2        X3       X4        X5
1 Parteen Silo CE0001U21A1 52.69373 -8.609117 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.609428 52.71170 -8.604171 52.71145 -8.599072
2 Parteen Silo CE0001U21B1 52.69373 -8.609117 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.594033 52.67827 -8.598788 52.67689 -8.603870
3 Parteen Silo CE0001U21C1 52.69373 -8.609117 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.637082 52.69970 -8.634897 52.70260 -8.631898
4 Parteen Silo CE0001U21A2 52.69373 -8.609117 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.609381 52.70900 -8.604914 52.70879 -8.600579
5 Parteen Silo CE0001U21B2 52.69373 -8.609117 -8.609117 52.69373 -8.596295 52.68059 -8.600337 52.67942 -8.604657
        X6        X7       X8        X9      X10       X11      X12       X13      X14 Longitude.1 Latitude.1
1 52.71064 -8.594290 52.70929 -8.589977 52.70745 -8.586270 52.70518 -8.583286 52.70255   -8.609117   52.69373
2 52.67605 -8.609117 52.67577 -8.614364 52.67605 -8.619446 52.67689 -8.624202 52.67827   -8.609117   52.69373
3 52.70523 -8.628178 52.70749 -8.623855 52.70932 -8.619065 52.71066 -8.613961 52.71146   -8.609117   52.69373
4 52.70810 -8.596515 52.70696 -8.592849 52.70540 -8.589698 52.70347 -8.587161 52.70123   -8.609117   52.69373
5 52.67870 -8.609117 52.67846 -8.613578 52.67870 -8.617897 52.67942 -8.621940 52.68059   -8.609117   52.69373
```

A link to the data in dput format can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzkBEqPfozOOMGtxeFJoN3J1Q3c/view?usp=sharing)

In order to plot these points in Google Earth I believe you need to project them to a coordinate system which is done using the following code:

```
coordinates(sites) <- ~lon+lat
proj4string(sites) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

When my file only consists of columns 1:4 I can easily plot the site details using

```
plotKML(sites)
```

But now I wish to plot columns 5 through 22 for each observation but I can't figure it out.

Does the projection and coor piece not work when there's more than one lat long per row?

Can anyone comment on how plotKML works for plotting polygons when there are many coordinates in a spatialpointsdataframe?

Comment: Please provide your data set in an more accessible form. An easy way to do so is `dput()`.